# DataGridView refuses to bind

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I am trying to bind to a list. I have tried every example on the net, and my grid sits there placidly (without error). No columns and no rows. Before you ask, my List DOES have data in it, the properties are all public.

Here's my code:

```
public fLogForm()
{
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingList<LogTransaction> transactions = LogTransaction.GetTransactionsForLastXHours(24);
            dgTransactionList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgTransactionList.DataSource = transactions; 
}
```

I've tried every combination of turning AutoGenrateColumns on and off. Using regular LISTS instead of bindingList. I've even tried to manually define my columns - in which case I get rows but no data.

[image]

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check that the tags are right on this question - the winforms datagridview does not have the databind method mentioned in your accepted answer. Should this maybe be tagged for the asp.net datagrid, or maybe the winforms datagrid alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot a command:
    dgTransactionList.DataBind();

I recommand that you move
    dgTransactionList.DataSource = transactions;
to the databinding event, and in your public fLogForm() just put
    dgTransactionList.DataBind();. 
If you made other manipulation like filter or paging, you won't need any special manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `dgTransactionList.ItemsSource = transactions;` ?